# Properly Compress Data in Node.JS (GZIP)

Tags: node.js

```
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;                   
});

var newhead = res.headers;
newhead['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip';

// the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here

res.on('end', function () {                       
    response.writeHead(res.statusCode, newhead);
    //response.write(str); //<- works 

    //gzip function start
    zlib.gzip(str,function(_,result){
        console.log(_); //this returns null here
        // response.write(result); //does not work
        response.end(result);      //does not work                  
    });
    //gzip function end                                                                 
});
```

i have this process on my nodejs server, and i want to gzip it, The problem is when i add the gzip functionality it does not return anything, when i remove it everything is ok

- zlib is required already
- browser accepts gzip,deflate and sdch
  what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: The compression middleware for express.js uses zlib stream support to do the compression. Maybe looking at the source would help: https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/master/index.js

Comment: hello @slebetman im not using express just the `http` library

Comment: What I meant was, look at the express.js compress middleware for inspiration. It's all pure js code. Nothing magical.